# Mobile Safari and Android Chrome don't return correct screen resolution

Tags: javascript, css, dom

**on iPHONE5s(640*1136), mobile safari returns 320*568. window.innerWidth and innerHeight return 981*1409**

**on Compaq 8 1400(768*1024), Android Chrome returns 768*976.window.innerWidth and innerHeight return 
980*1103.**

1.How can i correctly detect the correct screen resolution with mobile safari and chrome?

2.Why window.innerWidth and innerHeight return values which are much larger than screen resolution?

```
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<script>
console.log(window.screen.width);
console.log("<br />");
console.log(window.screen.height);
console.log("<br />");
</script>
<body>
<br/>===================================<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think window.screen.width and window.screen.height always return viewport size in pixel, which is always 320*568 for iPhone5 and up, and 320*480 for iPHone4s and below.

window.innerWidth will return the actual pixel size. They are different.

You can check the viewport size of popular devices here: http://viewportsizes.com/?filter=iphone

In mobile phone, the viewport size is not always equal resolution, whereas in desktop computer, you can assume they are the same.

Comment: However, IPhone 5s's resolution is 640*1136. How it can return values larger than its physical screen resolution?

If i don't use viewport meta, i still get 320*568. Why is that?

Comment: How it can return values larger than its physical screen resolution? Because your browser window may larger then the phone screen, and part of window is cut off by phisical screen. You probably experience this situation often on desktop.

Comment: If i don't use viewport meta, i still get 320*568. Why is that? as I mentioned in the answer, window.screen.height will always return viewport size. You can assume viewport is a just virtual screen with 320*568 resolution. That's why viewport tag is introduced to overwrite that.

Comment: 1.If you look at my html, it shall be rendered within the physical screen. So i am still not clear why it gets larger values?

2.window.screen.height will first assume a viewport size even the viewport doesn't exist. If it doesn't find the viewport meta, then it will use actual pixel. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: 1. It is somehow hard to explain, but window.screen.width cannot be changed, whereas window.innerWidth can be assigned with any value. Maybe the browser did something with this number to allow wider content to pane. 2. window.screen.height will always return viewport size, meta tag just change the viewport size value. I think this way is better way to understand it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `wiewport` metatag to adjust page width to screen width on mobile device:

```
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 ...
</head>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

By the way, you will get not *physical pixels*, but *css pixels*, used to measure all elements that you define using `px` in css. For example, on all iPhones viewport width is 320px (for both retina and non-retina displays)--this is made to make pages look similar on various mobile devices, independently on pixel density.